# best way to execute a list of instructions (n=0 to n=20). stop, then return to line n

Tags: python

i'm not sure I was very clear the first time I posted this, so i'll try agian.
thanks for bearing with me.
I have a program for a procedure, the procedure incurs like a drying time overnight.
(i'ts for my machine shop but work with me here)
it's like this:

```
a1=input('enter 1 after cutting paper')
a2=input('enter 1 after gluing paper')
a3=input('enter 1 after drying all night')
a4=input('enter 1 after resuming the next day')
```

i would just write down: "stopped on line a3".
and I was planning on writing a "for loop" to "unpack the list".

it was recommended to me that I use a dictionary rather than list; however I don't really see the difference, especially since a list can be enumerated, while a dictionary cannot.

I was thinking I could use a for loop and somehow run each ith value of the list.

thoughts anyone?

edit:
okay sorry for not explaining it well:
maybe this will help:

"i'm looking for a way to store information in a list, where the information is executable."
then I want to run that list starting on line n.

so like a recipe, but can start at any line.

Comment: Please tell what do you want to achieve. What kind of list do you want to have by the program? And what is there to iterate since there's no any `List` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a list of actions:

```
actions = [
    'cutting paper',
    'gluing paper',
    'drying all night',
    'resuming the next day',
]
```

And then iterate through them:

```
for action in actions:
    answer = input('input 1 after ' + f'{action}')
```

... but I still don't know what your actual question is.  What do you mean by "stop"?  Are you saying that you can't leave the computer running overnight, and you need some way to resume your progress in the list when the computer starts again the next morning?

Answer (score 0):

I created the instructions on a separate .txt file. Then was able to index each step in the Py code. This works. I can also pass Py code through from the .txt document by adding a special character for the Py script to search for, then run the lines

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).